# why cucumber test results don't display examples name or steps?

Tags: maven, junit, cucumber

I've ran into some unexpected results running a project with cucumber 2.0+. I discovered when running my tests as Junit, the immediate output doesn't display the "Examples" names or steps, instead it repeats the "Scenario outline" name for each line of "Examples" table. As practice I tried running the demo project for Screenplay pattern "TODOMVC" from https://github.com/serenity-bdd/screenplay-pattern-todomvc, using the following dependencies for cucumber

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
   <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
   <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
   <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
   <version>2.4.0</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

I've tried executing the runner with (CucumberWithSerenity.class) as well as (Cucumber.class)
And this is how the JUNIT looks in my Ecplise.

[Junit report in eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Twv2h.png)

Executing the runner using the old info.cukes dependencies (1.2.5) produce result with example names and steps as expected.

Just wondering if anyone else has ran into this issue, or if I'm missing something?

Comment: Yep you are correct... Example details are no longer visible. Dont know the reason behind it. Maybe a look at the release notes could shed some light.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like its intended behavior in the new cucumber version. Sort of a quick-fix solution is to add junit = "--step-notifications" in the cucumberoptions, which will display the steps, but still no luck with showing the example names.

Answer (score -2):

In that case, you have add the below line of code
**stepNotifications=true**  in your TestRunner file